# Cross platform RTF control?

Tags: cross-platform, rtf

Does anyone know of an RTF control that can be used on Linux/Windows/Mac? It's unfortunate that I have to mention it, but it actually has to be able to save and open rtf files... unlike wxWidgets wxRichTextCtrl for instance.

Edit: Thanks to HappySmileMan for his reply. Better still if it's more of a standalone and not a part of a large library that it would depend on.

Edit: ... and it doesn't look like it can open rtf files... ugh.

Answer (score 1):

RTF is simply not that common; it's a messy format controlled by Microsoft, basically a text dump of the .doc format. The only open source RTF implementations I know of are in Abiword, OpenOffice, and KWord. All are cross-platform, but none probably qualify as "controls" to your liking (though abiword has a bonobo interface, and KWord has a KPart, so they can be embedded, albeit in a heavyweight fashion).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the feature you are looking for is in the Qt toolkit.

Some info on this can be found at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html

Answer (score 0):

Qt's control is HTML, not RTF (though foobar may  just mean rich text, in which case it would be fine)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what I want (cross platform rtf control that reads and writes actual rtf files) doesn't exist, at least not for free and open source.
...I'd accept this answer but it doesn't seem possible.